# n00b question, form callback and form_alter

Tags: 7, forms

My highly-n00b question is: suppose I have a form callback which could be used as argument to drupal_get_form().

How can I specify an ID for the form so I can compare it inside hook_form_alter against the given-as-argument $form_id?

This means: I want to give a form id to the form, e.g. "my-system-form", and distinguish it to apply some alter-logic (don't want to apply that logic to the rest of the forms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) has `$form_id` as an argument:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
```

Which is:

> String representing the name of the form itself. Typically this is the **name of the function that generated the form**.

(emphasis mine)

To understand the "typically" in there, have a read through the docs for [`hook_forms()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7) (chances are it won't apply to your situation, or if it does, you probably already know about it).

So, generally speaking, you can use:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'MYMODULE_some_form') {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or, the more specific [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), which will only be invoked for that specific form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_MYMODULE_some_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: My question is: when declaring the form and returning it as an array: where do I specify 'MYMODULE_some_form'? It's the name of the function creating the form specs? (i.e. the array)

Comment: Exactly right - so if your form callback function is `function MYMODULE_some_form($form, &$form_state) { ...`, 'MYMODULE_some_form' is the string you'll get in `$form_id`. Don't forget, you're passing that string to `drupal_get_form()` already, it's just being re-used